# VSTO 4 MSI failed to install on virtual machine

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, vsto, windows-installer, virtual-machine

Here's more detailed error code from verbose logging

> MSI (s) (C4:FC) [17:44:17:683]: Executing op:
>   ComponentRegister(ComponentId={39A436F1-525F-4D9C-95E5-01D682F0FB25},KeyPath=<\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.AddInAdapter.v9.0,version="9.0.0.0",publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a",processorArchitecture="MSIL",fileVersion="9.0.30729.4130",culture="neutral",State=3,,Disk=1,SharedDllRefCount=0,BinaryType=0)
>   MSI (s) (C4:FC) [17:44:17:683]: MSCOREE not loaded loading copy from
>   system32 MSI (s) (C4:FC) [17:44:17:683]: Assembly Error:Function not
>   defined in specified DLL.
>
> MSI (s) (C4:FC) [17:44:17:683]: Note: 1: 1935 2:  3: 0x8002802F 4:  5:
>   CreateAssemblyNameObject 6:
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.AddInAdapter.v9.0,version="9.0.0.0",publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a",processorArchitecture="MSIL",fileVersion="9.0.30729.4130",culture="neutral"
>   DEBUG: Error 2908:  Could not register component
>   {39A436F1-525F-4D9C-95E5-01D682F0FB25}. MSI (s) (C4:FC)
>   [17:44:19:227]: Product: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office
>   Runtime (x86) -- The installer has encountered an unexpected error
>   installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this
>   package. The error code is 2908. The arguments are:
>   {39A436F1-525F-4D9C-95E5-01D682F0FB25}, ,
>
> MSI (s) (C4:FC) [17:44:19:227]: Executing op:
>   ComponentRegister(ComponentId={B25064D6-77BB-4B1B-B4CC-F8EDF50C7B6D},KeyPath=<\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.AddInAdapter.v10.0,version="10.0.0.0",publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a",processorArchitecture="MSIL",fileVersion="10.0.31119.0",culture="neutral",State=3,,Disk=1,SharedDllRefCount=0,BinaryType=0)
>   The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this
>   package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code
>   is 2908. The arguments are: {39A436F1-525F-4D9C-95E5-01D682F0FB25}, , 
>   MSI (s) (C4:FC) [17:44:19:243]: Assembly Error:Function not defined in
>   specified DLL.
>
> MSI (s) (C4:FC) [17:44:19:243]: Note: 1: 1935 2:  3: 0x8002802F 4:  5:
>   CreateAssemblyNameObject 6:
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.AddInAdapter.v10.0,version="10.0.0.0",publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a",processorArchitecture="MSIL",fileVersion="10.0.31119.0",culture="neutral"
>   DEBUG: Error 2908:  Could not register component
>   {B25064D6-77BB-4B1B-B4CC-F8EDF50C7B6D}. MSI (s) (C4:FC)
>   [17:44:20:226]: Product: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office
>   Runtime (x86) -- The installer has encountered an unexpected error
>   installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this
>   package. The error code is 2908. The arguments are:
>   {B25064D6-77BB-4B1B-B4CC-F8EDF50C7B6D}

I have tried to re-install **.NET 4 client profile** then re-install **VSTO 4** but still no gain.  Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have admin right on the machine?

Comment: yes. UAC is not disabled though

Comment: Try [installing full-blown .NET 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718). I'm not sure .NET client profile will work with VSTO runtime. Although [this post says it is officially supported](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2008/09/16/vsto-and-the-net-framework-client-profile-christin-boyd.aspx).

Comment: VSTO does support .NET client profile.

Comment: In that case - it sounds like [Office needs to be reinstalled or repaired](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110823212457AALN3NA). You should also get the [latest Windows Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8483).

Comment: Did you already install the [Office Primary Interop assemblies](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508)?

Comment: nope, PIA not installed yet. I think I will just reinstall office 2007, and then do vsto 4 runtime installation again.

Comment: @SilverNinja just out of my curiosity, how did you know that my MSI installer wasn't 4.5?

Comment: @woodykiddy Try installing the PIA before the VSTO runtime. Based on your error message I wonder if VSTO is trying to access one of the PIA DLLs.

Comment: thanks everyone for giving comments and ideas. I got it working on my virtual machine. I did whole a lot re-installations but all worth it.

Answer (score 0):

This has been reported in another forum. Apparently if no components of Office 2010 have been installed in the machine in particular the message can be ignored. I certainly found that in my case that I only have Excel 2013, there were no issues with the Add in and it works fine despite the error message.